# How to replace color by another on ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-color

I would like to **change (map) white color to blue color**. How can I do this on `ImageView` in Android? I tried `setColorFilter` by `PorterDuff` / `LightingColorFilter` / `ColorMatrixColorFilter` but I can't figure out how to set it up. There is a transparent background around the image.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Background Tint color function in xml or java code.

or

I would suggest another way. Take on frame layout and place view and then image view.
white portion in image should be transparent use PNG image.
and you can give color to base view color which ever you want.

Comment: Your solution is not a good idea because the image may not have a transparent characters. Question was about: map white color to another color.